# google maps api additional search box

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am struggling to introduce a second search to place a marker like the first search.
I have worked out the coding as below for a general search and marker place and as you can see and have added an extra search box but cannot work out how to make that search box do the same as the first.

Basically I am trying to mark two separate locations simultaneously with one submit button.

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction please

```
    <!-- Google Maps and Places API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">    
        //declare namespace
        var up206b = {};

        //declare map
        var map;

        function trace(message) 
        {
            if (typeof console != 'undefined') 
            {
                console.log(message);
            }
        }


        up206b.initialize = function()
        {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.070264, -118.4440562);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        }

     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();`

       up206b.geocode = function() 
{
    var address = $('#address').val();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } 
        else 
        {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}



up206b.geocode = function() 
{
    var address = $('#address').val();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } 
        else 
        {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}

var address = $('#address').val();

</script> 
</head>
<body onload="up206b.initialize()"> 



    <div style= "float:left">



    </div>



    <div style="width:380px; height: 100%; overflow:auto; float:right; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;"> 
        <h1>Map Search</h1>   


        <div style="border:1px solid #ccc; background:#e5e5e5; padding:10px;">
            <input type="text" id="address">
            <input type="text" id="">
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="up206b.geocode()">
        </div>

    </div> 




    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%; margin-left:400px;"></div> 



</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get value of both inputs, geocode the values that exist and add them to the map.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <!-- Google Maps and Places API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">    
      
      //declare namespace
      var up206b = {};

      //declare map
      var map;

      function trace(message) 
      {
        if (typeof console != 'undefined') 
        {
          console.log(message);
        }
      }

      up206b.initialize = function()
      {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.070264, -118.4440562);
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 13,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
      }

      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

      up206b.geocode = function() 
      {

        var addresses = [ $('#address').val(), $('#address2').val()];

        addresses.forEach(function(address){
          if(address){
          geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) 
                           {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
            {
              map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: results[0].geometry.location
              });
            } 
            else 
            {
              alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
          });
          }
        });
      }

    </script> 
  </head>
  <body onload="up206b.initialize()"> 

    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width:380px; height: 500px; overflow:auto; float:right; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;"> 
      <h1>Map Search</h1>   

      <div style="border:1px solid #ccc; background:#e5e5e5; padding:10px;">
        <input type="text" id="address">
        <input type="text" id="address2">
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="up206b.geocode()">
      </div>

    </div> 

    <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;"></div> 

  </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: hi,Thanks for that. but the trouble I am now having is that nothing happens when you click on submit. It does for the single use before I changed it but now doesn't for either inputs. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you very much. For some reason when I changed the code myself it didn't work but by copying and pasting yours it did weird but thanks.